# Prime ideal factorisation degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]=\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)}$ for $p$ a rational prime.

Why is it true that if an ideal $I$ of the form below in $R$ has prime factorisation $P_1^{e_1} \cdots P_n^{e_n}$ then $e_i \vert p-1$?

The form is $I=(\beta)$, where $$\beta=\alpha^{S},$$

and where $S=\prod_{e|l-1, \hspace{1mm} e \ne l-1}1-\sigma^e$, $a \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is `semi-primary', and $\sigma$ is a generator for $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Z})$.

Here `Semi-primary' means "in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$, coprime to $p$ and congruent to a rational integer modulo $(1-\zeta_p)^2$".

Comment: This https://gyazo.com/f7f7710010512a2cdd35c550614d359a is what has caused my confusion.

Comment: No, there's no reason for this to be true. For example $I$ might be the $p^{th}$ power of some prime ideal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, I'll edit to include only the more restrictive case. Thank you.